# How to jump back for a second in a video like on YouTube?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I build a game that is based on a video. The video is played from the half of it. When the button is pushed the video needs to jump a second back. The problem is that in fact it jumps to a specific point. How can I fix that?

```
    /// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void onFlower(View view) {
            VideoView myVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            myVideo.seekTo(myVideo.getCurrentPosition() - 1000);
    }

    /// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        /// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        ///locking the screen on portrait
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ///locking the screen on portrait
        boolean bool1 = false;
        /// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VideoView myVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        myVideo.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.degreesvideo);
        myVideo.seekTo(26000);
        myVideo.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, JavaScript has nothing to do with Java.